# How to get scrap web entire page data without physically scrolling?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am using the following code to extract information of [this](https://airtable.com/shrqYt5kSqMzHV9R5/tbl8c8kanuNB6bPYr?backgroundColor=green&viewControls=on) webpage, but it only fetches first 18 rows of information. How can I ensure that I am loading 2063 rows of information.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url= "https://airtable.com/shrqYt5kSqMzHV9R5/tbl8c8kanuNB6bPYr?backgroundColor=green&viewControls=on"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)


content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
table1 = soup.find("div",{"id":"table"})

driver.quit()

company_names = []
for i in table1.find_all('div',class_="line-height-4 overflow-hidden truncate"):
title = i.text
if(title.startswith('http')):
continue
company_names.append(title)

print(company_names)
print(len(company_names))
```

I have tried the following 4 snippets of code for scrolling through the webpage, but none of them work (I am not sure if this step is even needed):

Method 1:

```
ScrollNumber = 50
for i in range(1,ScrollNumber):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(1,5000)")#scrolling to said coordinates
    time.sleep(2)
for i in range(1,ScrollNumber):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(5000,1)")#scrolling to said coordinates
    time.sleep(2)

driver.close()
```

Method 2:

```
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Method 3:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

no_of_pagedowns = 38

while no_of_pagedowns:
elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
time.sleep(1)
no_of_pagedowns-=1
```

Method 4:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
elem.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working code using `selnium-wire`:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire
from seleniumwire.utils import decode as sw_decode


# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Go to the Google home page
driver.get('https://airtable.com/shrqYt5kSqMzHV9R5/tbl8c8kanuNB6bPYr?backgroundColor=green&viewControls=on')

# Access requests via the `requests` attribute
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:

        # Find the target request
        if request.url.startswith('https://airtable.com/v0.3/view/viwA14Z1pM69YIsaW/readSharedViewData'):

            # Decode byte data into string
            data = sw_decode(request.response.body, request.response.headers.get('Content-Encoding', 'identity'))
            data = data.decode("utf8")

            # Write
            with open('data.json', 'w') as file:
                file.write(data)
```

---

**Old answer:**

I am not sure if this will help, but if doing it manually also works for you, you can use developer tools for it.

1. Press F12 to open developer tools.
2. Go to Network tab and refresh the page.
3. Find the request which has a large size, starting with `redSharedViewData`
4. Click on the request
5. Go to preview tab
6. Right click on the top level and chose `Copy value`
7. Open a new text file and paste there, and save as JSON

You can now work with the JSON data using python or any other tools of your choosing.

**Note:** Make sure scrapping the data will not create any legal issues for you first.

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway we can fetch this json via code? Instead of doing it manually.

Comment: You can use Selenium-wire: https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/

Comment: @random_name I added a working code with Selenium-wire to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @farshad. This seems to have done wonders for me. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

might not be exactly how you expect but... have a look.
You can use scrapy shell command to scrape the entire data in the webpage, using Scrappy.

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

    url = "http://example.com"
    response = HtmlResponse(url=url, body=requests.get(url).text)
    print(response.css('html').get())
```

Comment: I am able to retrive the HTMlL response, but it does not have any of the information required.